# Movement of participle clauses

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Consider this sentence of mine, please:

1. *John is an American dancer and choreographer, **specializing in contemporary dance***.

Are 2) and 3) below grammatical?

2. ***Specializing in contemporary dance**, John is an American dancer and choreographer*.
3. *John, **specializing in contemporary dance**, is an American dancer and choreographer.*

Comment: They are all grammatical—although they could have very subtly different nuances in meaning. Assuming you wanted to overanalyze them. (For all intents and purposes, they mean the same thing.)

Comment: They are all correct, but the sentence would work better if the participle phrase were modifying *an American dancer and choreographer* rather than *John*: *John is an American dancer and choreographer specializing in contemporary dance.* (#1 without the comma)

Comment: In 1. it's a depictive adjunct giving descriptive information about John. In 2. and 3. it's a supplementary adjunct, not a modifier.

Comment: @BillJ, But, being two different types of adjunct does not make any difference in their meaning, right?

Comment: That's right: they are all depictive adjuncts, 1. being a modifier in clause structure, 2. and 3. being supplements. Sorry, I should have made that clear. Btw, 1. is preferable by far.